# No output when running powershell command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, sccm

I am trying to get the list of members/computers from a collection in SCCM. When I run the command below I don't get any errors and it takes about 2 minutes before it finishes but it never shows any output? Just goes back to the prompt. Any ideas why it wont show me any output? Thank you

```
import-module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\ConfigurationManager.psd1'
$GetDevices = Get-CMDevice -CollectionName "All Systems" | Select Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put the result of get-CMDevice in a variable but you never echo it, try
`$GetDevices` (or `echo $GetDevices`) and you should see the output